# Locked out with no service!

Tags: sim-unlocking

I was fiddling with the lock your SIM card features and locked it, but the password I used now will not open it, and it is locked with no service, screen says screen is PUK locked and is asking for  an 8 digit password to change the PIN code, which the one I typed when trying to set it was only 4 digits. I think I must have clicked change password right before it locked me out. What do I do now?

Answer (score 1):

Some SIM cards have PUK codes printed on the punch out cards that the SIM card came from.
T-Mobile for example has PUK code printed on the plastic punch out.

Comment: That's correct. All SIM cards I've seen come with PIN1, PIN2 (both 4-digit), PUK1, and PUK2 (both 8 digit). If you locked the PINs, you can use the PUKs to unlock. If you locked the PUKs, too – well, then you need a new SIM.

Comment: If I locked the PUKs by accident, then if i was changing the PIN for the SIM card, wouldn't the PIN be the same? I literally just did it, so I know what I typed. I am wondering if I am typing the right PUK though. Which number on the SIM is the one it wants? I'm running out of tries! Should I just take it to Verizon? Can they reset it?

Comment: Yes, they would either unlock it or simply replace your sim for you.